# Play framework - make form validation async - compilation error

Tags: scala, playframework

Trying to use map (line 6) instead of using Await (lines 3-4) results in compilation saying Cannot resolve overloaded method 'Action' marking the first line.
I think the problem is in the last line of the function using fold which now has another value type returned from errorFunction.
can someone help understanding whats happening and how to make create user fully async?

```
def createUser = Action { implicit request: MessagesRequest[AnyContent] =>
    val errorFunction = { formWithErrors: Form[Data] =>
      val readAllResponse = Await.result(usersDao.readAll(), Duration.Inf)
      BadRequest(views.html.listUsers(readAllResponse, formWithErrors, postUrl))
      // TODO - try to make it async.
      // usersDao.readAll().map(allUsersList => BadRequest(views.html.listUsers(allUsersList, formWithErrors, postUrl)))
    }

    val successFunction = { data: Data =>
      val user = User(id = data.id, firstName = data.firstName, lastName = data.lastName)
      // call to DAO
      val createUsers: Future[User] = usersDao.create(user)
      Redirect(routes.UserController.listUsers()).flashing("Info" -> "user added!")
    }

    val formValidationResult = form.bindFromRequest
    formValidationResult.fold(errorFunction, successFunction)
  }
```

code for readAll():

```
def readAll()(implicit transaction: Transaction[User]): Future[List[User]] = Future {
        println(s"Reading all users...")
        Thread.sleep(500)
        transaction.modelObjectsList.toList
      }
```

Error (when uncommenting line 6):

Compilation error[type mismatch;
found   : play.api.data.Form[controllers.UserForm.Data] => scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]
required: play.api.data.Form[controllers.UserForm.Data] => play.api.mvc.Result]

Comment: It's recommended to first read the documentation

Answer (score 1):

That fails in compilation because you are using the sync Action, and pass a Future. For that line to work you need to change your Action to an async Action, and it should be as simple as this:

`Action.async {/*your code here*/}`

Comment: now having: type mismatch;
 found   : controllers.UserForm.Data => play.api.mvc.Result
 required: controllers.UserForm.Data => scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]

Comment: Did you change to Action.async and uncommented that line?

Comment: Ahh I see, you also need to return a Future in your success function, try to wrap the Redirect part with a Future

Comment: thanks, works. more general question: Action should not be async by nature?

Comment: I'm now having the following in successFunction:

usersDao.create(user).map(_ => Redirect(routes.UserController.listUsers()).flashing("Info" -> "user added!"))

create may throw exceptions, how will you handle it (keeping the required returned value type)?

Comment: Well that is entirely up to you, it depends on what you need/want to do when a error occurs, but you can just use a fold in create and do something with the exception, otherwise do what you already do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216468/discussion-between-amir-lasry-and-pedro-correia-luis).